# Are wallpapers downloaded when updated automatically using an rss feed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, rss

So I set up my desktop to automatically grab images from the earthporn reddit site using this guide: https://www.reddit.com/r/shaunc/comments/4bojku/howto_use_a_subreddit_like_rearthporn_as_your/

I was just wondering... are the images saved on my computer (which may need deleting in the future) or are they simply downloaded + deleted?